# java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException with awaitTermination

Tags: java, parallel-processing, executorservice

I have a parallel execution set up like this

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
List<Callable> tasks = ...

for (Callable task : tasks) {
    executorService.submit(task);
}

executorService.shutdown();

try {
    executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (Exception e) {
    .. log exception
}
```

When I deploy the code I'm getting this exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task ExecutorService$2@5486ec58 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@7b993426[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 4]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
```

When I remove the .shutdown(), I don't have the problem, but it blocks until the 1 second is up. Any ideas on what's causing this?

Comment: Your executorService, judging by your exception has definitelly been terminated. It's very strange that it got terminated somehow before a submit of a Callable task.

Comment: what version of Java are you running?